# Codeigniter: The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with PHP CodeIgniter (using JetBrains PhpStorm). I want to upload a song, but I got the message:

> The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.

I successfully uploaded other file types (smaller), but when I try to upload this song I got an error.

I've set this in my php.ini but it still fails:

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M;  
post_max_size = 128M
```

Anyone got some idea about solving this problem?

Comment: When I echo: phpversion() and ini_get('post_max_size')) I got answers: Current PHP version: 7.0.0; Max size: 8M. Btw evern if it's 8M max size, I'm trying to upload ~ 4MB song i got error The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.

Comment: Hard to say anything definite, what if you try to set directives in a .user.ini or  .htacces file and check max_size config param from CI_Upload class just to  start?

Comment: Can help me about first suggestion? And about CI_Upload I've put         $config['max_size'] = 128; but nothing helps?

Comment: Try to put 0 in max_size, if I'm not mistaken, it means that CI doesn't check filesize, regarding my first suggestion, this post describes every possible option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: I've put 0 in config['max_size'] and I successfully now upload files (even mp3 songs) up to 2MB size, if I try to upload >2MB I got message The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file. I'm in trouble, can't find out where is max size set to 2MB, I've set in php.ini 128MB upload and post max size? btw. I am using  wamp (php 7 and apache 2.4.17) maybe that info can help

Comment: OK, now it isn't a problem of CI anymore, please check the linked post about upload file size and set params so that ini_get will return right values in a script, I believe it's gonna be the end of trouble

Comment: Also I wanted to tell you that ini_get prints me: post_max_size = 128M. But still when i try > 2M song, can you tell me why am I $finfo = $this->upload->data(); when I try to echo $finfo['file_size'] i realize that that variable is empty?

Comment: Well, if both directives are set and you see their value in a script, I don't know what may cause a problem. Could it be a client-side validation? To be honest, I don't have any other idea

Comment: Constantine thanks for all support, I've just put all files from wamp/bin, then I've searched "2M" and I found 2 times I think one was in some apache settings, changed them to 128M now it works great! Thanks again!